# Why will my physics 2D raycast not display or work correctly?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, physics, raycasting

Basically i wanted to make a raycast for jumping but for some reason the distance of the raycast is wrong and never changes and the position of it is so wrong i cant even seem to find it:

```
    ray2D = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector2.up, .1f, GroundedLayers);
    Debug.Log(ray2D.distance);
    isGrounded = groundCheck();
```

Grounded layers do not include the player, distance always returns as 0, grounded is always false and the gizmos line only draws when i open the prefab and not at all in the scene:

[image]

here the distance is set to .1f but displays the same as 1f

(EDIT: ok so i checked and for some reason the raycast happens around 0, -1 even tho thats nowhere near the player transform?)

[image]

Comment: How do you display the ray?

Comment: @derHugo gizmos.drawline(transform.position, ray2D.point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the raycast was detecting an invisible trigger so i had to put it on another layer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Vector2.down instead?

Alternative things to try:

Is the player in the scene the same as the prefab?
Increase the distance.
Add a new GameObject at the feet of the player, reference that in your script and call the Raycast from there.
Is ray2d a RayCastHit2d?
Are your ground object tags correct, including all grammer/caps?
Try outputting in debug, ray2d.collider.name to see what you're actually hitting.
If you're using a rigid body, try rigidbody2d. position instead of transform.position

Do you have the player selected in the hierarchy? This is needed to see the gizmos.

Comment: `This is needed to see the gizmos` .. if you draw the Gizmos in [`OnDrawGizmosSelected`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDrawGizmosSelected.html) yes .. not if draw them in [`OnDrawGizmos`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDrawGizmos.html) ...

Comment: everything you mentioned ive already done sadly, also i have already tryed vector2.down with no luck